# Excel - concatenating cells where reference number matches

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, concatenation

I have a worksheet with many rows. Some of the rows share reference numbers (contained in, say, column A). What I'd like to do is, where a row shares a reference number with another row, I'd like to concatenate the data contained in, say, column B from both of those rows to a new cell in, say, column C.

Example:

<kbd>Col A</kbd>      <kbd>Col B</kbd>         <kbd>Col C</kbd>                    
<kbd>12345</kbd>     <kbd>Robert</kbd>      <kbd>Robert, David</kbd>      
<kbd>12345</kbd>     <kbd>David</kbd>        <kbd>Chris</kbd>                    
<kbd>54321</kbd>     <kbd>Chris</kbd>

Comment: In your example, which is very clear and well laid out, col C is Surname, FirstName - I'm not sure if the order is going to be possible unless the surname always occurs before the firstname (reading down the column(). Is that a problem? +1

Comment: @DaveRook I don't think the OP has Col C as Surname, FirstName it's a combination of values from Col B. Robert and David are the first two values and because they both have 12345 in Col A the OP wants them together.

Comment: Brad is correct. Col C is just a place to dump the concatenation. I don't mind which order they go in particularly, but even if I did, it seems like that's a separate issue.

Comment: This one is so well formatted and the other is so poorly formatted that I can't tell if this is really a duplicate. Also there's no mention of avoiding VBA in this question.

Comment: The fun with this begins when you try to pull it off with a formula ;) And I've seen some of the excel wizzards do that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the VBA approach. Assuming Excel 2007 or later; first few steps will differ if you're using a pre-Ribbon version of Excel.

1. [Enable the Developer Tab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb608625.aspx)
2. Click on "Visual Basic" on the Developer Tab on the Ribbon
3. Right-click on "VBAProject (whatever-your-sheet-is-named.xls*)" and do Insert -> Module in the context menu
4. Paste in this code

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Function allquixotic(param As Variant, search As Range, values As Range, Optional absolute As Boolean = False) As String

   Dim sep As String, retval As String
   Dim i As Integer, rownum As Integer
   Dim look As Range, j As Range

   sep = ", "
   retval = ""
   For i = 1 To search.Rows.Count
   Set look = search.Cells(i, 1)
   If absolute Then
           rownum = look.Row
   Else
           rownum = i
   End If

   If look.Value = param Then
           If absolute Then
                   Set j = values.Worksheet.Cells(rownum, values.Column)
           Else
                   Set j = values.Cells(i, 1)
           End If
           retval = IIf(retval = "", retval & j.Value, retval & sep & j.Value)
   End If

   Next

   allquixotic = retval

   End Function
   ```
5. Use the worksheet function (feel free to rename it) by using a formula like

   ```
   =allquixotic(A1,$A$1:$A$15,$B$1:$B$15,true)
   ```
6. Use the fill handle to put the formula in all the cells

The parameters are the following:

`=allquixotic(look_cell, key_range, value_range, absolute)`

`look_cell`: The first parameter, should be a **single cell** or a **value literal**. Valid input includes things like `3`, `$6.25`, `"Hello"`, etc. This is the value that you are trying to find in `key_range`.

`key_range`: This should be a **range** of cells (more than one cell); if `absolute` is true then you will get very strange results unless this is a **contiguous** range (all the values are in sequential rows).

`value_range`: This should be a **range** of cells (more than one cell); if `absolute` is true then you will get very strange results unless this is a **contiguous** range (all the values are in sequential rows).

`absolute`: If true, then we will use the **absolute row number** (relative to the number of rows in the entire spreadsheet) of each "found" row in the `key_range` to determine what row to extract a value from `value_range` on. If false, we will use relative numbers; for instance, if we find a match in the **third** row of `key_range`, then we will extract the value from the **third** row of `value_range`. Recommended value is FALSE, or you can omit it to default to that.

**Note**: This function does not support the case where the key and value ranges are in **columns**, but it should be fairly easy to adapt it to that.

Also, if you specify multiple columns in either the key_range or the value_range, only the leftmost column will be used.

Comment: Thanks, allquixotic. And I didn't rename the function as your name is fantastic!

Answer (score -1):

Would this work for you?  Set the formula in C2 as

```
=IF(A2=A3,B2 & ", " & B3,B3)
```

It assumes your data is sorted on ColA so that reference numbers are grouped together.

QUESTION:  Can there be more than 2 names with the same reference number in ColA?

Comment: Sadly, as the document is likely to change, shift about and grow, having absolute references to cells makes it a little difficult to implement. I was hoping for something a little more flexible.

Comment: I think you will need a VBA macro to loop the columns

Comment: Those aren’t absolute references; they are relative (offset) references.  If they were absolute references they would have dollar signs (`$`) in them.  As shown above, you can extend (drag/fill) cell `C2` to `C3` and you will automagically get `=IF(A3=A4, B3 & ", " & B4, B4)`.